# How do I get the amount of comments and upvotes on my meme command? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, reddit

I currently have this command in discord.js with an api that uses reddit. I'm just wonderting, how would I get the number of upvotes and comments that the post has? I've looked everywhere and cannot find the answer to this. Support is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

```
const { MessageEmbed, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js')
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Returns a random meme from reddit.",
    aliases: [],
    run: async (bot, message, args, prefix) => {
        const subReddits = ["memes"]
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('PURPLE')
            .setImage(img)
            .setTitle('Meme from r/memes')
            .setURL('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes');

            message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own fetch instead of using randomPuppy, since it just fetches and doesnt give back the url

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Inside of the run function: (using imgur since thats what randomPuppy pulls from, imgur pulls from reddit)

```js
run() {
  const subReddits = ["memes"];
  const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];
  const url = `https://www.imgur.com/r/${random}/hot.json`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  const posts = json.data
     .filter(f => msg.channel.nsfw || !f.nsfw);

  if (!posts.length) return message.channel.send("No posts, maybe try in a nsfw channel");

    const post = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
    const redditUrl = `https://www.reddit.com${post.reddit}`;
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('PURPLE')
        .setImage(`https://imgur.com/${imageData.hash}${imageData.ext.replace(/\?.*/, '')}`);
        .setTitle("Post from r/" + random)
        .setURL(redditUrl)
        //this might be imgur upvotes or reddit upvotes idk
        .addField("Votes", post.score);
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Got some of the code from https://github.com/dylang/random-puppy/blob/master/index.js

Anyways there might be some errors with this (like user inputs non existent subreddit) so its up to you to error check